# Backstretch copy output from loop to a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-backstretch

I have a full screen background slideshow powered by the Backstretch script.
I'm trying to create a caption for each slide and would like to display the information in

```
<span class="cap"></span>
```

inside of

```
<div class="caption"></div>
```

The span is part of a list that populates the slideshow and is hidden.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/g84hK/7/

Thanks for any advice or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`backstretch.show`](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch#backstretchshow) event as you suggest in you fiddle like a get the `cap` element array.

> Backstretch will fire a "backstretch.show" event everytime a new image
>   loads, triggering a function that is passed the event and Backstetch
>   instance. If you listen for that event, you can, for example,
>   coordinate other changes to coincide with your slideshow.

Code:

```
// coordinating image captions with slides
$(b).on('backstretch.show', function() {
    $(this).data("backstretch").index;
    $(".caption").html(cap[$(this).data("backstretch").index].html());
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g84hK/9/